# MFT pipeline line unexpected exit

Tags: trace, ms-media-foundation

I have a MFT pipeline as below:

[image]
FaceDraw and FaceDetect are custom MFTs. This pipeline is running fine for first few frames and all of sudden it exits.

I tried analyzing it using MFTrace and narrowed to a spurious evenet as below:
*CMFPresentationClockDetours::GetTime @0000004BF1114E50 Time 20687020hns*

This is not expected and suddently popping up. This event further leading to below set of events that are causing pipe to drain-off

*CMFClockStateSinkDetours::OnClockStop @0000004BF98AFE88 System time 668039142ms
CMFClockStateSinkDetours::OnClockStop @0000004BF98AFB28 System time 668039142ms
CMFTransformDetours::ProcessMessage @0000004BF1838970 Message type=0x00000000 MFT_MESSAGE_COMMAND_FLUSH, param=00000000*

So the question is, what are the ways to figure out the initiator for this event? Are there any better tools for debugging issues like this?

Initially I suspected EVR, but the removal of EVR from the pipeline is not making any difference.